# Globally setting ipv6only=off

Tags: nginx, ipv6

Since an update my nginx server is only available via IPv6 and not IPv4 while my config contained

```
listen   [::]:80 default_server;
```

Now I've changed this to

```
listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;
```

and the server is available via IPv4 again.
This seams to be due to the changes in [nginx 1.3.4 (section “Changes with nginx 1.3.4”)](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.4).

Since I have more than one server configuration on the same mashine I would like to set the `ipv6only=off` globally is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: It's not very clear in the answers here, but `ipv6only` now defaults to enabled if you are using the single-line listen directive in your question example. It's better to explicitly define a listen line for both IPv4 and another for IPv6, and the you don't need to worry about `ipv6only` at all (delete the phrase if exists).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just went through this with an upgrade from 1.0 to 1.4.

Since only a single listener is actually bound to any given port, it's sufficient to specify `ipv6only=off` in *any one* of your `listen` directives.

So, in my default `server` blocks, I have:

```
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off default_server;
```

and

```
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off default_server;
```

All of the other `server` blocks merely specify the original `listen` directives. And it works; any virtual host is reachable via either IPv4 or IPv6.

You could also add it to *all* of them, but that's not really required. Adding it to any one of them is sufficient.

However, because the `ipv6only=` flag is Linux-only, I do not use this construct anymore. My current directives specify both IPv4 and IPv6 explicitly, such as:

```
listen [::]:80 default_server;
listen 80 default_server;
```

Comment: What listen block did you write in the other servers? For my all requests to the other servers on IPv4 end up on the default_server.

Comment: It's in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` which serves the `server_name _`. If you're having trouble, check nginx's error log; if you just did a `service nginx reload` it will say OK even if the configuration file check failed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What exactly did you add to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`?

Comment: I put the above `listen` directive in that particular `server` block. The rest I left untouched.

Comment: Ah, ok because I have my server configs in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` resp. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: OK, so you're on Debian rather than Red Hat. There should be a default server enabled in there somewhere that you can use.

Comment: Dear god, the cringe from seeing space as the delimiter for parameters to options in a .conf file, shudder.

Comment: When using two directives for explicitly listening on both IPv4 and IPv6, it it necessary to put the directives on all the server blocks, or just one?

Comment: @mcont Yes, both are necessary; otherwise nginx will not match requests to that `server` block for the not `listen`ing protocol.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to @Michael Hampton's answer (but you have to touch all files) is to insert

```
listen 80;      # listen for IPv4
listen [::]:80; # listen for IPv6
```

for all servers.

---

Strange is, that inserting `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off` for more than one server results in

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:3
```

And a mix of `listen 80;` and `ipv6only=off` (in different servers) results in

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```